# android delete specific contact programmatically

Tags: android

Right now, this code is working
`ops.add(ContentProviderOperation                   .newDelete(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)                       .withSelection(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID+"=?",new String[] {sid}).build());`

However it creates unknown record and seems that its the deleted contact. Do I need something to make it work properly?

Answer (score 8):

I made it work this way:

```
public static boolean deleteContact(Context ctx, String phone, String name) {
    Uri contactUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(phone));
    Cursor cur = ctx.getContentResolver().query(contactUri, null, null, null, null);
    try {
        if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                if (cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME)).equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
                    String lookupKey = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY));
                    Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_LOOKUP_URI, lookupKey);
                    ctx.getContentResolver().delete(uri, null, null);
                    return true;
                }

            } while (cur.moveToNext());
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getStackTrace());
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As explained in

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.RawContacts.html

CONTACT_ID field in RawContacts is a link to aggregated contact. Deleting RawContact via `ContentProviderOperation.newDelete` will make this field null (as I've found). When RawContact is actually deleted is up to Android sync and aggregation. I needed to delete specific contact from specific account, so deleting via RawContacts, not aggregated Contacts worked for me. To check if RawContact had been deleted, I used:

```
    ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();

    ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();

    Cursor curRawContacts = contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, null,
            ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE + " = ? AND " + ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME
                    + " = ?", new String[]{"MYTYPE", MyAccount}, null);

    int size = curRawContacts.getCount();


    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {

        curRawContacts.moveToPosition(i);

        //getColumnIndexOrThrow(String columnName)
        //Returns the zero-based index for the given column name, or throws IlleidRawContactgalArgumentException if the column doesn 't exist.
        String idRawContact = curRawContacts.getString(curRawContacts.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.RawContacts._ID));
        String idContact = curRawContacts.getString(curRawContacts.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTACT_ID));

        // if link to aggregated contact is null, than raw contact had already been deleted
        if (idContact != null) {
```

Answer (score 0):

`newDelete` method with ContentProvider **is not working for me**. It deletes all the infos in the contact but it leaves an **empty (null null)** contact in your phonebook.

This is why I had to use **ContentResolver** with `delete` method.

I wanted to delete contacts created with my app with specific `SOURCE_ID`.

I have set `CALLER_IS_SYNCADAPTER` to `true`.

So this is how I have managed it:

```
Uri contactUri = RawContacts.CONTENT_URI.buildUpon().appendQueryParameter(ContactsContract.CALLER_IS_SYNCADAPTER, "true").build();
String whereClause = RawContacts.SOURCE_ID + " = ?";
String[] args = new String[]{contactId};

int deletedRawContacts = context.getContentResolver().delete(contactUri, whereClause, args);

if (deletedRawContacts > 0) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Delete OK");
} else {
    Log.d(TAG, "Nothing to delete");
}
```